# Want to create a barplot with 2 bars x groupe all numeric values in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I want a barplot with the level (`niv`) on the x axis and both bars for `pour_water` and `pour_organic` on the y axis following the level.
Thanks!

niv_alti = level, pour_eau = water, pour_MO = organic matter

```
no   niv_alti   pour_eau  pour_MO                                   
2   -0.22   20.26   0.70               
1   -0.27   23.84   1.37    
3   -0.35   15.87   32.12   
5   -0.40   23.59   1.31    
4a  -0.55   19.84   1.26    
4b  -0.60   22.74   15.08   
4c  -0.71   32.40   NA  
4e  -0.71   22.09   0.62    
4d  -0.85   8.08    5.54
```

Some simple code I did for only one but I want to get 2 bars;

```
barplot(height = mat$pour_eau, names = mat$niv_alti, xlab = "site", ylab = "eau")
```

Answer (score 1):

we can use `par` with `mfrow=c(1,2)` argument (1 row and 2 columns)

```
mat <- read.table(textConnection('no niv_alti pour_eau pour_MO
2 -0.22 20.26 0.70
1 -0.27 23.84 1.37
3 -0.35 15.87 32.12
5 -0.40 23.59 1.31
4a -0.55 19.84 1.26
4b -0.60 22.74 15.08
4c -0.71 32.40 NA
4e -0.71 22.09 0.62
4d -0.85 8.08 5.54'),header=T)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
barplot(height = mat$pour_eau, names = mat$niv_alti, xlab = "site", ylab = "% eau")
barplot(height = mat$pour_MO, names = mat$niv_alti, xlab = "site", ylab = "% mo")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can reshape the data from wide to long format and then use the formula interface of `barplot`.

```
pour_vars <- grep("^pour", names(mat), value = TRUE)
long <- reshape(
  mat,
  varying = pour_vars,
  v.names = "no",
  direction = "long"
)
long$time <- pour_vars[long$time]
barplot(no ~ id + time, long, beside = TRUE, col = "grey")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you accidentally want to create a column chart instead of a bar chart?

Check out this solution:

```
mat <- read.table(textConnection('no niv_alti pour_eau pour_MO
2 -0.22 20.26 0.70
1 -0.27 23.84 1.37
3 -0.35 15.87 32.12
5 -0.40 23.59 1.31
4a -0.55 19.84 1.26
4b -0.60 22.74 15.08
4c -0.71 32.40 NA
4e -0.71 22.09 0.62
4d -0.85 8.08 5.54'),header=T)

library(tidyverse)

mat %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  pivot_longer(contains("pour"), names_to = "pour", values_to = "y") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(niv_alti, y, fill=pour, group=pour))+
  geom_col()
```

[image]